# XPath Query: Selecting a node where there is only 1 child node

Tags: xml, xpath

```
<Shop>
        <Managers>
            <Manager>Bob</director>
        </Managers>
        <staff>
            <supervisor>Bob</supervisor>
        </staff>
</Shop>


    <Shop>
        <Managers>
            <Manager>Jim</director>
            <Manager>John</director>
        </Managers>
        <staff>
            <supervisor>Jack</supervisor>
        </staff>
</Shop>
```

I am looking an xpath query which will just output where the number of managers = 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following XPath expression which only selects the `Shop` elements which have *exactly one* `Manager` element as `Managers`'s children:

```
//Shop[count(Managers/Manager) = 1]
```

**P.S.:**
I replaced all `</director>` closing elements with `</Manager>` elements to make your XML well-formed.